# How to check the combobox text is in the dropdownlist? [Visual Studio]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, dropdown

My program have a Combobox and DropDownStyle property is DropDown, the dropdownlist include 1,2,3,4,5. And I have a `if-else` method that is

```
if(Combobox.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {do something} 
else
    {do other thing}
```

If i input 1 in the Combobox, the program will do something, but if i click 1 from the dropdownlist, the program will do other thing.

How to make the program will do other thing even i input 1 in the Combobox, not just click from the dropdownlist?

Answer (score 0):

I would utilise the 'Text Update' and 'Selected Index Changed' Events against the combobox, have a differing event for each one, unless it's imperative you have code that needs to run all in one function.

Text Update for when you type in '1'

Selected Index Changed for when you select a seperate item.

```
    private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("UPDATE");
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("SI");
    }
```

Comment: My program will take the record about the information of Stock, it have a combobox to make the classification, if someone input is not in the dropdownlist, my program will auto add it in the list. 
The problem is even my input already in the list, but the program can not pass the if-else condition